# Full file name in Sublime Text when there are a lot of files

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

I have opened a lot of files in Sublime text. Now it is very difficult to read file names. It is showing just few letters of each file name. Attaching screen shot for better understanding.

[image]

How can I see full name of each file? I wanted to fit full name of each file on screen. I don't want to hover over the file to see its full name.

Answer (score 1):

You could edit `Packages/Theme - Default/Default.sublime-theme` and change `tab_min_width` to a higher value (and save it and restart ST or resize the window to see the change) or use a different theme which has a wider minimum tab width.

However, I'd highly recommend upgrading to ST3 - there is a new setting added in build 3048 called `enable_tab_scrolling` which will help keep tabs wider, and enable you to see them all.

Comment: This is working but now another problem has occurred. I have opened about 30 files. After changing the value of min_tab_width, now full names of file are coming but only few files are coming which can fit to my machine screen. I am seeing 7 files name in front of me. It's fine. Other files are also exist and I can navigate to them by scrolling. But even on scrolling this bar is not moving forward. It is still showing me 7 files. I am unable to see the name of 8th file in front of me even when I have reached there. Hope that you will get my point.

Comment: The answer to this is to change to ST3 that handles this better than ST2. Are you prevented from making the change? If not then it's time to make the change.